Quarkus native Error with GraalVM: Unresolved Type Issue during Parsing with PGobject
I'm developing a Quarkus extension for an ORM framework. However, I'm encountering some issues when testing with native mode.
The error message I'm receiving is:
Error: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.postgresql.util.PGobject. This error is reported at image build time because class xxx.xxx.xxx.sql.dialect.PostgresDialect is registered for linking at image build time by command line and command line.


The more detailed error message is as follows:
Detailed message:
Error: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.postgresql.util.PGobject. This error is reported at image build time because class xxx.xxx.sql.dialect.PostgresDialect is registered for linking at image build time by command line and command line.
Error encountered while parsing xx.xxx.xxx.runtime.graal.Substitutions$PostgresDialectSubstitutions.unknownReader(Substitutions.java:37) 
Parsing context:
   at root method.(Unknown Source)

Error: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.postgresql.util.PGobject. This error is reported at image build time because class xxx.xxx.sql.dialect.PostgresDialect is registered for linking at image build time by command line and command line.
Error encountered while parsing xxx.xxx.sql.dialect.PostgresDialect.lambda$unknownReader$0(PostgresDialect.java:136) 
Parsing context:
   at static root method.(Unknown Source)

This seems to be related to the parsing process during the GraalVM build, particularly with the usage of PGobject in my codebase. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:
I'm using Quarkus framework for my application.
I have a class PostgresDialect which includes a method unknownReader that uses PGobject.
I've tried various approaches such as replacing lambda expressions with anonymous classes and registering substitutions with GraalVM's Feature interface, but the issue persists.
Could anyone provide insights into why GraalVM is encountering this "Unresolved Type" issue and how to resolve it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
The following is the orm framework code
@Override
 public Reader<?> unknownReader(Class<?> sqlType) {
    if (sqlType == PGobject.class) {
            return (rs, col) -> rs.getObject(col.col(), PGobject.class);
        }
        return null;
    }

Here's what I did with the quarkus extension
public class Substitutions {

    @TargetClass(className = "xxx.xxx.sql.dialect.PostgresDialect")
    public static final class PostgresDialectSubstitutions {

        @Substitute(polymorphicSignature = true)
        public Class<?> getJsonBaseType() {
            return null;
        }

        @Substitute(polymorphicSignature = true)
        public Object jsonToBaseValue(Object json, ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws Exception {
            return null;
        }

        @Substitute(polymorphicSignature = true)
        public Object baseValueToJson(Object baseValue, JavaType javaType, ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws Exception {
            return null;
        }

        // This code is the cause of the error
        @Substitute(polymorphicSignature = true)
        public Reader<?> unknownReader(Class<?> sqlType) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Even when my dialect is not Postgres, I still need to include the Postgres dependency.
So, I referred to Quarkus's code, but it didn't work.
It seems that no matter how I replace the unknownReader method, GraalVM still tries to find PGobject.
Thank you in advance!

Does the error also occur if you check for PGobject.class in the unknownReader method?

The unknownReader method is located in the PostgresDialect class, so there shouldn't be any issue when the dialect is Postgres. Theoretically, when the dialect is not Postgres, the PostgresDialect class should not be invoked.

The code could be invoked since native-image doesn't necessarily know about the dialect.

Wouldn't it work if I override the method using @Substitute?

Quarkus is supposed to handle PGObject already: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/214761792d5e132c28562e39e3414f2439f6b6fc/extensions/jdbc/jdbc-postgresql/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jdbc/postgresql/deployment/PostgreSQLJDBCReflections.java#L13-L49
You should check that:

You're using a recent version of Quarkus
You have quarkus-jdbc-postgresql in your dependencies

If you checked all the boxes above, you should open an issue to the Quarkus project -- with a reproducer.

My issue is that even when I'm using a different dialect, GraalVM still checks for PGobject.class in the PostgresDialect class. I'm not using Quarkus's ORM, but rather encountered this problem while writing another ORM extension.

I know you're not using Hibernate ORM, but the fact remains: if you have a dependency to postgresql-jdbc, you must have a dependency to quarkus-postgresql-jdbc, or things like this will occur. If you want to have multiple dialects, some of which will have unresolved dependencies (because the JDBC driver isn't in the classpath), well... you'll  need to make GraalVM aware of which dialects are used, and which are not. com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.Delete is one way to do that.

I've tried deleting it, but other classes use PostgresDialect for some checks. If I delete it, it will cause errors. Do I have to rewrite any class that uses PostgresDialect?

Let's put it that way: GraalVM's static analysis must conclude that the PostgreSQL JDBC classes cannot possibly be called. So you must use GraalVM substitutions to trim all references to PostgreSQL JDBC classes from your call tree. If you can't delete PostgresDialect, then you need to substitute that class for another one that will both never use any PostgreSQL JDBC class, and work for your framework's "checks".

Note that another approach is to instantiate dialects during static init only (using a STATIC_INIT recorder in Quarkus), and use substitution to make it clear to GraalVM that the native image will never instantiate any (further) dialect. It's the approach taken by the Hibernate ORM extension, but depending on your framework it may be complex.

Thank you for the detailed explanation. I would like to know if there are any similar examples available for either of these approaches that I can refer to? This would be very helpful. Thank you!

As I said, the static init approach is complex, so I'm afraid I can't point to specific lines of code, but you can study the Hibernate ORM extension in Quarkus -- it will probably take a while, and I can't affort spending the time to guide you through that.

For the substitution-only approach... I'm not sure what examples to point you to, as it's really about using GraalVM annotations to "delete" code. Maybe https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/214761792d5e132c28562e39e3414f2439f6b6fc/extensions/jdbc/jdbc-postgresql/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jdbc/postgresql/runtime/graal/DisableSSPIClient.java? Just... you know, replace problematic methods that call classes which you don't want to be accessed.
